# Trouble Inserting ID from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to allow users to insert a comment onto the latest blog. However, I've come across a problem when trying to structure the INSERT statement. Basically, I've realized primary key for blog_id is located in the blogs table and not in the comments table, as that only contains the foreign key for it. So I'm wondering, how do I grab the highest blog_id from the other table and put it into an INSERT statement?

```
INSERT INTO comments(blog_id,user_id,user_post) 
SELECT MAX(blog_id)
     , $ud_us AS er_id
     , $ud_user_post 
  FROM comments
```

Comment: so users can never comment on an old blog? can't you put the blog id in the form as a hidden form field?

Comment: your use case doesn't make a lot of sense to me. however, why don't you split the problem into 2 sql statements. one for getting the lates blog id and one for inserting the comment ...

Comment: You cannot use this max blog id concept. What happens when another user creates a new blog while another user is creating a comment. You will attach this comment to the wrong blog

Comment: You must store the blog_id and user_id either in the comment_edit form or the session, and use those in the INSERT

Answer (score 0):

Using `join` to query data from different tables.

```
    INSERT INTO comments (blog_id, user_id, user_post) SELECT
    MAX(btn.id),
    $ud_us AS er_id,
    $ud_user_post
FROM
    comments c
INNER JOIN <blog_table_name> btn ON c.blog_id = btn.id
WHERE
    <btn.columnA = ???>
```